# Error in dunntest: Error in if (tmp$Eclass != "factor") { : the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I get an error when I try to run the Dunntest on my data and I can't figure out what's causing it.

I have 4 groups with ordinal discrete data, the Kruskal-Wallis test suggest a significant difference between groups but I can't run the dunntest afterwards.

Any help is appreciated.

```
> mast_cells
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   group score
   <ord> <dbl>
 1 1         1
 2 1         1
 3 1         1
 4 1         1
 5 1         1
 6 2         3
 7 2         4
 8 2         2
 9 2         1
10 2         3
11 3         2
12 3         1
13 3         2
14 3         3
15 3         3
16 4         3
17 4         2
18 4         3
19 4         2
20 4         2
> mast_cells$group <- ordered(mast_cells$group ,
+                             levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
> kruskal.test( score ~ group, data = mast_cells)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  score by group
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 9.1875, df = 3, p-value = 0.0269

> library(FSA)
> dunnTest(score ~ group,
+          data = mast_cells,
+          method="Benjamini-Yekuteili")
Error in if (tmp$Eclass != "factor") { : the condition has length > 1
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dunTest` function does not accept formula as an argument, you need specify your data vector as the first argument, and factor as the second one. Additionally if you choose Benjamini-Yekuteili adjustement method for multiple comparison, option `method = "by"` should be specified.

See the code below:

```
library(FSA)

mast_cells <- structure(
  list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
  score = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), 
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
                "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), 
  class = "data.frame")


dunnTest(mast_cells$score, mast_cells$group, method = "by")
```

Output:

```
Dunn (1964) Kruskal-Wallis multiple comparison
  p-values adjusted with the Benjamini-Yekuteili method.

  Comparison          Z     P.unadj      P.adj
1      1 - 2 -2.6685305 0.007618387 0.11199029
2      1 - 3 -2.1348244 0.032775359 0.16059926
3      2 - 3  0.5337061 0.593544894 1.00000000
4      1 - 4 -2.4999917 0.012419622 0.09128422
5      2 - 4  0.1685388 0.866159449 1.00000000
6      3 - 4 -0.3651673 0.714986507 1.00000000
```